# Using actions on React without a Dispatch function is correct?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, redux, components, dispatch

I'm implementing Redux on React and it's currently working, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I have a redux folder with 3 files: actions, reducers and store.

Actions has this code:

```
export const SETTER_USER = "SETTER_USER"

export const setterUserAction = ({ email, username, role, lastVideo }) => ({
  type: SETTER_USER,
  payload: { email, username, role, lastVideo }
})
```

I'm calling this action from the component, this is the code on the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setterUserAction } from '../../redux/actions'
...

const Login = ({ navigation, user, setUser }) => {
...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
})

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
  setUser: setterUserAction
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

I used to have the action inside the component, which I can imagine is not ideal. So I moved it to an actions.js file. But now I'm not using a dispatch function, which feels weird as dispatch is part of the whole pattern. So, what do you think? Is this correctly implemented? Or it's just working by luck?

Comment: Is `mapDispatchToProps` an object? I saw you have `()` in when define it

Comment: @Viet You are right, the ( ) have nothing to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `mapDispatchToProps` as an object. It was recommended by `react-redux` team: You can read more about it in here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object

> We recommend always using the “object shorthand” form of mapDispatchToProps, unless you have a specific reason to customize the dispatching behavior.

**Update**: If you are using Function component with Hook, you should use the React-Redux hooks API: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

> We recommend using the React-Redux hooks API as the default approach in your React components.
> The existing connect API still works and will continue to be supported, but the hooks API is simpler and works better with TypeScript.

But if you are using Class Component. You should use `connect` with `mapDispatchToProps` as an object instead of as a function.

Comment: @RamaProg In addition to that, it is also recommended to use the hooks over `connect` where possible, so you might want to look into that: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api
and in modern redux in general, as you are writing a very old style of redux there and might be following outdated resources: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: Thank you very much @phry. I'm sure you are right, I'm not an expert, but I seem to recall reading that connect was better. Also, the react-redux documentation uses connect. Are you sure in this case I should use the hooks useSelector and useDispatch?

Comment: @Viet Please correct me if I'm wrong. What you are saying is that I was lucky enough to use the recommended shorthand object whitout knowing about it. So dispatch is happening on the background, I'm just not calling it myself.

Comment: Pretty much, yes! :) And as linked, we do actually recommend using the hooks API as the default: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks. We just haven't had time to switch out some of the React-Redux docs that still show `connect` in the tutorial.